# Find values in common between two arrays

Tags: ruby

If I want to compare two arrays and create an interpolated output string if an array variable from array `y` exists in `x` how can I get an output for each matching element?

This is what I was trying but not quite getting the result.

```
x = [1, 2, 4]
y = [5, 2, 4]
x.each do |num|
  puts " The number #{num} is in the array" if x.include?(y.each)
end #=> [1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can use the set intersection method [`&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-26) for that:

```
x = [1, 2, 4]
y = [5, 2, 4]
x & y # => [2, 4]
```

Comment: This method also works for more than two arrays. All arrays must contain the desired term, though.

Comment: will this work if the indices aren't the same for the same value?

Answer (score 17):

```
x = [1, 2, 4]
y = [5, 2, 4]
intersection = (x & y)
num = intersection.length
puts "There are #{num} numbers common in both arrays. Numbers are #{intersection}"
```

Will output:

```
There are 2 numbers common in both arrays. Numbers are [2, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, so the `&` operator appears to be the only thing you need to do to get this answer.

But before I knew that I wrote a quick monkey patch to the array class to do this:

```
class Array
  def self.shared(a1, a2)
    utf = a1 - a2 #utf stands for 'unique to first', i.e. unique to a1 set (not in a2)
    a1 - utf
  end
end
```

The `&` operator is the correct answer here though. More elegant.