# How to find matching values in ruby array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Have arrays
`[1, 2, 5]` and `[1, 2, 3]`
I would like to extract matching values, if there is a method like:

`[1, 2, 5].match([1, 2, 3]) #=> [1, 2]`

Is there any method on array, thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find values in common between two arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230227/find-values-in-common-between-two-arrays)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Very simple:

```
[1,2,5] & [1,2,3]  #=> [1,2]
```

Other useful array operations include:

```
[1,2,3] | [1,3,4]  #=> [1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3] - [1,3,4]  #=> [2]
[1,2,3] + [1,3,4]  #=> [1,2,3,1,3,4]
```