# Dynamic intersection in Ruby Arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an set of Arrays. The number of Arrays is dynamic, it could be one, could be 100. In this example it's 3:

```
arr = [[1,2,3,4], [2,4], [2,3,4]]
```

What I need as result is to find same (intersecting) value(s) from all arrays. So result should be:

```
#=> [2,4]
```

How it could be done a proper way?

Comment: Have you already looked at the simpler 2 case example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230227/find-values-in-common-between-two-arrays

Comment: Sure. But my `arr` is dynamic as I mentioned before. It could be [[1] [1,2,3,4]] or like it the example above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arr.reduce &:&
#⇒ [
#  [0] 2,
#  [1] 4
# ]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Array#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-26) to find the (set) intersection of arrays:

```
arr.inject(:&)
# => [2, 4]
```